# node JS get request, receiving an SSL alert number 40, works in curl and python

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, openssl

We are in the process of moving some of our backends over to node and ran into the following issue (both on linux and mac). This is our curl which works:

```
curl --insecure --cert-type pem --cert CERT.pem  "https://USER:PASS@www.website.com/info"
```

In python we use the request library (which also works):

```
    import requests
    r = requests.get('https://USER:PASS@www.website.com/info', auth=('USER', 'PASS'), cert='CERT.pem')
```

As I mentioned we tried this in JS with no success:

```
const request = require('request')
const options = {
    url: "https://www.website.com/info",
    auth: { 
        'user': 'USER', 
        'pass': "PASS",
        'sendImmediately': false
    },
    insecure: true,
    cert: fs.readFileSync("CERT.pem")
};


request.get(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(res)
    console.log(body.url);
    console.log(body.explanation);
    resolve(JSON.parse(body.explanatio))
});
```

We get the following result:

```
Error: write EPROTO 4514557376:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1536:SSL alert number 40

    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:87:16) {
  errno: 'EPROTO',
  code: 'EPROTO',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

I understand this isn't really a JS issue, however I don't quite understand SSL the issue and how to fix it. For really appreciate an inside on how to continue debugging / fixing the issue.

Comment: I got an exactly the same error, any luck you got a way to fix it?

Comment: OK I solved the issue, by switching client, I am using nextjs, I cannot use `fetch` or `axios` but `https` lib is OK.